# C# HttpWebRequest Get method

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to replicate a login to a website with http requests. My problem is that the First request via browser (Get method) to the Home Page already issued a cookie which I cant replicate via http requests. After, running Fiddler I saw that when I am landing to the home page via browser the Request Header is :

```
GET http://www.somewebsite.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.somewebsite.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,el;q=0.8
**Cookie: _asd=sssssss-fffdd-sdd-ffff-sdddffdfd**
```

to replicate my Http request

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.somewebsite.com/");
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);

        request.UserAgent = useragent;
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch");

        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Timeout = 45000;

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

So the produced header is :

```
GET http://www.somewebsite.com/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Referer: http://www.somewebsite.com/
Host: http://www.somewebsite.com/
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

What I am missing? Thanks

Comment: What you are missing? a question. What is the problem?

Comment: What contains cookies variable ? it is not post to HttpWebRequest

Comment: The problem is that I cant replicate the Cookie in the Get method... So According to the Fiddler, the browser first request to the HomePage is via Get method, but as I see in the Header it is already containing the cookie. How it is possible?

Comment: Make two requests to the site and use the same CookieContainer instead of creating a new one for each request.

Comment: You mean, first Post to get Cookie and then Get to Set cookie? I tried that and while it is getting Cookiee in the container it is in different format..